# Migration is duplicated but it's really not

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

On a server I have this:

```
select * from schema_migrations ;
 version | inserted_at 
---------+-------------
(0 rows)
```

But when I'm running "migrate" in my Phoenix application via edeliver

```
$ mix edeliver migrate production --verbose
```

I get this:

```
response: RPC to 'my_app@127.0.0.1' failed: {'EXIT',
                                      {#{'__exception__' => true,
                                         '__struct__' => 'Elixir.Ecto.MigrationError',
                                         message => <<"migrations can't be executed, migration version 20160827023221 is duplicated">>},
                                       [{'Elixir.Ecto.Migrator',
                                         ensure_no_duplication,1,
                                         [{file,"lib/ecto/migrator.ex"},
                                          {line,254}]},
                                        {'Elixir.Ecto.Migrator',migrate,4,
                                         [{file,"lib/ecto/migrator.ex"},
                                          {line,235}]},
                                        {rpc,'-handle_call_call/6-fun-0-',5,
                                         [{file,"rpc.erl"},{line,187}]}]}}

MIGRATE DONE!
```

Neither do I have 2 files with the same migration number locally.

Comment: Can you post the names of the files in `priv/repo/migrations`? (`ls priv/repo/migrations`)? I think the error means you have 2 files starting with `20160827023221`.

Comment: @Dogbert **Neither do I have 2 files with the same migration number locally**

Answer (score 12):

I had a same kind of problem after renaming the migration file. Deleting generated application files by using 'mix clean' command helped in my case.

Answer (score 4):

Running `mix ecto.migrate --step 1` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to clean the project manually and didn't work. Then I used `mix clean` and it worked for me.